# How to get strings after specific patterns

Tags: php, regex

I have strings that looks like this:

```
searchUniqueCode("name", "FF14_1451_DAD4");searchUniqueCode("name", "F1F1_1451_DAD4");
searchUniqueCode("name", "FF14_3121_DAD4");searchUniqueCode("name", "SH14_1451_DAD4");
searchUniqueCode("name", "FF14_1131_DAD4");searchUniqueCode("name", "FF14_1451_D31F");
```

And I am trying to get all of the strings under " " after the common pattern `searchUniqueCode("name",` Like the `FF14_1451_DAD4`.

Is there any way I can achieve that using PHP?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
searchUniqueCode\("name",\s*"\K[^"]+
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hugOKm/1)**

**[Check code here](https://onecompiler.com/php/3xq53wr73)**

---

**Explanation:**

- `searchUniqueCode\("name",` - matches `searchUniqueCode\("name",`
- `\s*"` - matches 0 or more occurrences of a white-space followed by a `"`
- `\K` - un-matches whatever has been matched so far and starts the match from the current position
- `[^"]+` - matches 1 or more occurrences of any character that is not a `"`. This is the desired match that will match everything until the next occurrence of `"`

Or

You can capture the desired values in group 1 as shown below:

[`searchUniqueCode\("name",\s*"([^"]+)"`](https://regex101.com/r/hugOKm/3) - [Working code here](https://onecompiler.com/php/3xq547ngg)

Comment: can you also help me with this pattern? [data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;base64,]   [data:image/jpeg;base64,]  Basically I need a regex in where I can get the content that are between the "data:" and ";base64"

Comment: @Karl I would suggest you to open a new thread for a new question. Anyways, for the examples you have mentioned, you can use the regex [`(?<=data:).*?(?=;base64)`](https://regex101.com/r/1h42hB/1)

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!! you are a god in regex!